# What is perform_async in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I want to know about perform_async in sidekiq. As I could not found any documentation on this while everyone is using this.

So can someone please explain this to me or provide a resource.

Comment: `perform_async` just gets pushed to the queue right away

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`perform_async` - a method that push your job with your params in the async queue (create a record in your async backend, Redis by default), to allow Sidekiq catch and perform it on the order of queue

Source: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/e2f92e8279d1947aa45eb86acc73f9ebe7a92c9c/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb#L6-L43